# Need to grab 2 elements of a list from large file

Tags: python, list, parsing

There are 2000+ lines in the source file, look like this (see below) , and I need the **last three** **elements** only to a output file, the source file type is "list". Can open file and print file, but can't understand how to parse original and need to do all 2000+ lines. Probably a loop of some kind?

```
230105_184945    18.100 Rx FT8     -4  0.3 1172 KL7AIR N2AIE EN42
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thats quite easy. Have a look to all chapters of [W3schools section on lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp), and also [W3schools section on opening files](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp)

Anyway, assume you have the file hello.txt.

first you open it

```
file = open('hello.txt')
```

Then if you want to iterate on it using the readlines() method. This returns a list where every element is a line of the file

```
for i in file.readlines():
    print(i)
```

you can parse and work with the variable *i* in the loop. Each iteration of the loop will read a new line of the file, moving the file pointer to the end of the file.

readlines() method will move the pointer to the end of the file, so if you want to read the file again, you will have to use the seek() method

```
file.seek(0)
```

This will move the pointer to line 0.

if you want to access the last three lines of the file:

```
file.readlines()[-3:]
```

If you want to create a list with every line and access the last three words lets split the line (a string) with the split() method, this will *cut* down the string with the specified separator, so do this:

```
for i in file.readlines():
    line = i.split(' ')
    last_3_words = line[-3:]
```

otherwise if you want to exclude the last three elements

```
for i in file.readlines():
    line = i.split(' ')
    without_last_3_words = line[:-3]
```

you can use -3 to indicate third last element, and the : is like a range, for example [1:-3] is from the second element to the fourth last element.

Do not forget to upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks got all that but you missed the question.  "Don't want "last three Lines of file" want the last three elements of each  line. IE,  " KL7AIR N2AIE EN42"

Comment: ok, so when you read the lines (our i in the loop) you can split the string in a list with the split() method like this i.split(' '). so you can create a line variable like this
line = '1 2 3 4 5 6'.split(' ')

then you can access the last three elements in line like that
line[-3:]. Do not forget to upvote my answer, i will edit it

Comment: how do i " upvote and accept the answer"